# My brush is not affect in weight paint mode

Tags: weight-painting

I was in weight paint mode and everything painted fine except I could not see the tool settings. I found how to make them visible. However for some reason after I did that, I cannot paint anything. I did not change away from the "draw brush." I tried changing to "add" instead of "Mix" but that didn't work. I tried changing the weight, radius, and strength of my brush but still I could not paint.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out that for some reason you can now select individual faces to select.

On the top left of this picture there is a face and a vertex option to show their respective geometry. So when you are in that mode you can deselect all faces so that now you cannot have any influence on any faces. All you have to do is deselect everything with either  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> which is the default for 2.8 or press <kbd>A</kbd> again to toggle between selected and deselected if you are using the old hotkeys.

[image: ![enter image description here]